# Python code not running when i change the directory to /var/www/html

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

When i run the python code which is using tensorflow in a Desktop directory , it is running perfectly, but when i run the same code in /var/www/html , it is giving the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Loader.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

How to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Did you install tensorflow as global package or in an virtualenv? Did you follow the installation guide on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux?

Comment: i installed it under the conda environment....

Comment: Most likely, you installed it in just the conda environment and not globally. As soon as you try to run the program outside of the conda environment it hits the dependency issue as the package it requires is not there

Comment: Sorry, I do not use conda - and I cannot help you. But I think this could be the problem. When you run the code in www/html it does not know the conda enviroment (and the installed packages) ...

Comment: tensorflow is running perfectly in /var/www/html directly  but when i root by "sudo su"inside the /var/www/html directory  and then run the program , then it is giving above mentioned error...

Comment: that's probably because you installed tensorflow to your local anaconda packages, which would not be available to the root user